# NA values in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm doing some numerical calculation in Haskell and I would like to have `NA` values inside vectors and matrices, like in R or Matlab. The most natural way I thought about was to use `Maybe` to handle these values and use `Nothing` as `NA`.

It works in general by lifting operations, but I wanted to use HMatrix as well to get a faster code. In order to use it properly I would need to do an awful lot of instances of `Maybe a` to the different classes defined in the code (and I'm not even sure all of them are possible).

Is there some kind of library that does this kind of work, or I will have just to define myself all the operations?

Answer (score 3):

This is not what you want probably, but look at `NaN` ("not a number"):

```
nan = 0/0

main = do
    print $ nan        -- NaN
    print $ nan * nan  -- NaN
    print $ nan + 0    -- NaN
    print $ nan / 2    -- NaN
    print $ isNaN 0    -- false
    print $ isNaN nan  -- true
    print $ nan == nan -- false
```

Note the last line: `NaN` is not equal to itself.